# CSS clip-path on mobile Safari acts like content-box

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a container that is cut with `clip-path` and has some background color. Works perfectly in every browser that supports `clip-path` but mobile Safari (probably desktop Safari too, can't test).

https://codepen.io/Deka87/pen/PXVNgQ

HTML:

```
<!-- Container -->
<div></div>

<!-- Clip -->
<svg>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <path d="M 0 0 V 1 A 5 5 0 0 1 1 1 V 0 Z"></path>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  min-height: 300px;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 100px 0;
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clip);
  clip-path: url(#clip);
}

svg {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

The problem in Safari is that when `clip-path` is applied the background of the container acts like its `background-clip` property is set to `content-box` i.e. it doesn't go behind the padding's so those areas remain blank.

Comment: Safari on mac looks the same as chrome on mac.

Comment: @Huangism, thanks for your comment. Does this mean that paddings affect the backgrund size or they don't?

Comment: Actually I take that back, the 100px padding does not appear in safari and appears on chrome, on mac

Comment: So it must be mobile Safari only.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue and was able to work around it by adding an extra wrapper div to the element that is being clipped and moving the padding into a child. It's not truly a fix, but allowed me to move forward.

HTML:

```
<!-- Container -->
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Clip -->
<svg>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <path d="M 0 0 V 1 A 5 5 0 0 1 1 1 V 0 Z"></path>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clip);
  clip-path: url(#clip);
}

.child {
  background-color: gray;
  min-height: 300px;
  padding: 100px 0;
}

svg {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

See example here:
https://codepen.io/mprquinn/pen/8b1e4e6004e989491f294a8899a94ec7

Hopefully this is helpful!